# L'origine del water!

Tags: word-usage, etymology

> Il termine "water", è l'abbreviazione (pronunciata all'italiana) dell'inglese water-closet (letteralmente: stanzino dell'acqua). Il termine viene usato dall'inizio degli anni 60 e diventa sempre più popolare dagli anni 80 come risulta da [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tazza%20del%20water%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctazza%20del%20water%3B%2Cc0) (tazza del water).

L'adozione e l'uso di anglicismi è un fatto comune per la lingua italiana, ma in particolare per questo termine mi chiedo come mai abbiamo adottato il corrispettivo inglese.  Forse perché i primi bagni erano importati dall'Inghilterra o per qualche altro motivo?

Comment: In catalano e in spagnolo abbiamo avuto esattamente lo stesso fenomeno.

Comment: In italiano ci sono vari esempi di vocaboli importati da una lingua straniera (spesso il francese, in questo caso anche l'inglese) per ragioni di delicatezza. Per esempio, "essere in *déshabillé*" invece di "essere nudo/nuda". Secondo me questo potrebbe essere un altro fenomeno di questo tipo.

Comment: @giomasce Mai sentito quell'esempio francese. Ho sempre detto "sono nudo" quando volevo dire "sono nudo", e volendo essere più delicato direi semplicemente "svestito".

Comment: Termine tipicamente eufemistico.

Comment: [Questo Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toilette%2Cwater&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoilette%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwater%3B%2Cc0) mi fa sospettare che l'andamento del termine sia dovuto a due fenomeni: **1** l'intervento del fascismo contro le "mollezze" lessicali e i francesismi che ha colpito _toilette_, risparmiando paradossalmente _WC_, e **2** la diffusione di massa dei sanitari in seguito al boom economico dopo la Seconda Guerra Mondiale.

Comment: io credo che il fenomeno abbia correlazione con la percezione di volgarità del termine "cesso".

Comment: @Mauro Vanetti: Non c'è alcuna prova che le cause siano quelle che citi. Inoltre, water può essere presente in opere e scritti del tardo novecento inteso come 'acqua', dato che quella parola in lingua originale non ha solo 'cesso' come significato.

Answer (score 3):

Non è un granché, ma ho trovato [questo articolo](http://rociodiazgomez.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/wc.html) secondo il quale molte lingue usano forestierismi per designare il "water" per un meccanismo simile all'eufemismo. Ad esempio, la Wikipedia afferma che il termine ["water closet"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flush_toilet#Water_closet) è stato coniato in Inghilterra intorno al 1870, ma adesso gli inglesi usano il vocabolo d'origine francese "toilet" e non più WC.

Sembra che l'origine dell'articolo sia il giornale spagnolo ABC.

Comment: La causa è esattamente questa: uno dei motivi più tipici del prestito è proprio l'eufemismo (o al contrario talvolta l'esigenza di aumentare l'impatto: *shock*). L'esempio di gabinetto > toilette è riportato da Fusco in *Cos'è l'interlinguistica*, dedicato appunto ai vari tipi di prestito